# Get_browser returns strange values even with updated browscap.ini defined in php.ini

Tags: php, html, vb.net, php-ini, browscap

Here are the things that i have already taken care of:

1. Downloaded updated copy of php_browscap.ini from http://tempdownloads.browserscap.com/ (used the 'use only with PHP' version ofcourse)
2. tried php_browscap.ini,lite_php_browscap.ini and full_php_browscap.ini 3. edited the php.ini file to: `[browscap]
   ;http://php.net/browscap
   browscap = "C:\xampp\php\extras\full_php_browscap.ini"`
3. confirmed that i have changed the correct php.ini file by checking php_info()
4. and yes removed that ; from ';browscap = .....'
5. restated the xampp server.

But still getting the strange values

`Array ( [browser_name_regex] => §^.*$§ [browser_name_pattern] => * [comment] => Default Browser [browser] => Default Browser [version] => 0.0 [majorver] => 0 [minorver] => 0 [platform] => unknown [platform_version] => unknown [alpha] => [beta] => [win16] => [win32] => [win64] => [frames] => [iframes] => [tables] => [cookies] => [backgroundsounds] => [javascript] => [vbscript] => [javaapplets] => [activexcontrols] => [ismobiledevice] => [issyndicationreader] => [crawler] => [cssversion] => 0 [aolversion] => 0 )`

Comment: Please post your answer as an answer instead of replacing your entire question with "I fixed it".  StackOverflow is a place for sharing questions an answers to benefit everyone... we're not here just to answer questions for you alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the browscap.ini file from http://tempdownloads.browserscap.com/

Answer (score 0):

The updated browser files are now located at http://browscap.org